# What is the recommendation polyurethane application when refinishing hardwood floors?

Tags: hardwood-refinishing

There is currently no furniture in the first floor. So before filling up the first floor with furniture I am wondering if I should refinish the floors.

**Floor History**

Three of the four floors are 20+ years old. I believe they the wood is white oak. Below are some pictures for reference. There is no noticeable gouges The floor is yellowed a bit.

### White Oak Hardwood

[image: Hardwood Floor 1]

[image: Hardwood Floor 2]

### White Oak Hardwood floor close up

[image: Hardwood Floor close up]

The fourth floor I believe is red oak. I am not too sure if the floor has been strained to match the kitchen cabinets. There is noticeable wear and tear. The floor is almost 10 years old.

### Red Oak Hardwood

[image: Red Oak Hardwood floor]

### Red Oak Hardwood with some wear and tear

[image: Red Oak Hardwood floor wear and tear 1]

[image: Red Oak Hardwood floor wear and tear 2]

**Questions:**

- How many coats of polyurethane should be used 2 or 3 coats?
- Is oil base or water base polyurethane the best options?

Note: There is lot of infomation on the web, mostly to intend to sell products. Thus seeking a non commercial response.

---

**References:**

- [How can I transition between rooms when refinishing hardwood floors?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/47246/how-can-i-transition-between-rooms-when-refinishing-hardwood-floors)
- [What is the recommended technique for refinishing hardwood floors?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/what-is-the-recommended-technique-for-refinishing-hardwood-floors)
- [Maintaining and Recoating Polyurethane Wood Floors](http://www.naturalhandyman.com/iip/inffloor/infrefinpoly.html)
- [How many coats of polyurethane for hardwood floors](http://www.woodflooringguy.com/2006/01/09/229/)
- [How many coats of oil poly?](http://www.brownstoner.com/forum-archive/2010/12/how-many-coats/)
- [Hardwood Flooring Colors - Species, Pictures & Properties](http://www.uptownfloors.com/species/general.htm)
- [American Hardwoods](https://youtu.be/x_vYYrF6x6I)
- [What is the difference between red oak and white oak hardwood?](http://theflooringgirl.com/blog/red-oak-vs-white-oak-hardwood-flooring-whats-the-difference.html)

Comment: One specific question at a time, please. SE isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: Your question begs only opinion based answers.  While your writeup is very organized, I agree with @isherwood, do you have a specific question or multiple separate questions that you cannot come to terms with after your research and ponderings?

Comment: @Damon, I will split the question. Also my research had left me confuse to how I should approach refinishing. Example is 2 coat of polyurethane sufficient or do you really need 3 coats. Essentially would like the community help me clear up confusion by providing pro and cons on options.

Comment: I would recommend getting a quote by a recommended and/or trusted wood floor contractor; at that time bounce such questions off of them for your specific situation, needs, and expectations.  We would be asking questions about use and wear (Kids? Home a lot?  Or usually out?), expected length of stay (years or decades) and/or timeline to sell again, resources (budget namely) available, expectations for length of time to keep the wood in the different spaces (possible floor changes in the future?), etc.   We would guide you based on your answers.

Comment: The only area I could say from the photos that needs stripping and refinishining is the ones where something heavy tore up the poly, how many coats I like 3 because that really gives a depth to the floor, another opinion is I prefer oil based over water based I have just had better looking finished projects in my opinion. Last what is the difference in red oak and red oak the color, with red oak I don't usually stain it but white I usually do add color oil based in both tint an poly.